# Short story about a lady (teacher?) caught skinny dipping by kids

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I recall long ago (30-40 years ago?) hearing or reading a story (maybe a short story, or a tale or joke told in a story).

Country setting: Tom Sawyer/Huck Finn or Little House on the Prairie type environment.

Young lady (school teacher?) is skinny dipping (swimming nude) in the local watering hole or stream or pond.

A group of young teens (some of her students?) come along a see her and start spying on her, but she quickly sees them. She tries telling/asking them to leave but they won't, and they start messing with her clothes she left on the shore.

She starts getting mad and yelling at them to go away, but they come even closer, so she is moving around trying to keep them from seeing her body in the water. While she is moving she bumps into something on the bottom. Feels it and realizes it's an old washtub.

Now she has something to cover herself with, she pulls it up and holds it in front of her and charges up on shore. Chasing the kids around the clearing who have her clothes, and telling them to leave.

About this time, she says something like "You kids know what I think...?"
And the kids reply something like "Yeah, you think there is a bottom in that washtub"

Comment: I know that one as a stand-alone joke involving a frying pan, but I don't know of somewhere in particular where it showed up.

Comment: In re reading this question again, I got a flash of that old grandpa character on the Hollywood Squares TV show from the 70s?  AND I was thinking maybe he (or another character like him) told it as a joke on the old Hee Haw TV show. Hee Haw was my father's favorite TV show so it was what we watched when it was on. (1 TV in house at the time)